# Reactive form: how to blur and submit in one click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

I have a Reactive Form (`#myform`) with a button `"foo"`, to which is attached `(click) = myform.submit()` so that the form will only submit when that button is clicked, and not on `Enter` events. The component listens for `Enter` events, and dispatches `blur` in that case, and the FormControls all have `{updateOn: 'blur'}` so `blur` events trigger updates (i.e., `valueChanges`, etc).

My problem is this: If I key data into an `Input` (or select an item in a `Select`) without hitting `Enter` or `Tabbing` out of the element and then click on the `"foo"`, i.e. `"Submit"` button it seems that clicking the `"foo"` button only causes a `blur` event without triggering submission of the form (through `myform.submit`). I.e., the `submit` gets "swallowed" by the `blur` event.

How can I set this up so that if I don't `Enter` or `Tab` out of an element, and immediately click `"foo"`, the element will be updated through the `blur` event AND THEN the form will ALSO be submitted?

I've tried things such as: 1. first processing the `blur` and then trying to programatically call `myform.submit()` in the component (by accessing the `Form` through `@ViewChild`), and 2. adding a `(blur)= (submitNow && setTimeout(()=>myform.submit(),50)` listener in the template view. At this point, I haven't even got this `setTimeout` call to compile, and none of the approaches I've tried seem to work so far.

The original code (simplified) is like this:
template `details.component.html`

```
<form #myform [formGroup]="form" method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/users/{{userID}}/details">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let sec of datArr">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let row of sec; let i = index">
                          <input type="text"
                          [appTag]="row[datColEnum.tabCol]"
                          (keydown.enter)="onEnter($event)"
                          tabindex = "{{row[datColEnum.tabCol]}}"
                          name="{{row[datColEnum.controlNameCol]}}" value="{{row[datColEnum.valueCol]}}" 
                          formControlName="{{row[datColEnum.controlNameCol]}}"/>
                </ng-container>
         </ng-container>
  <button name="foo" type="button" (click)="myform.submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

component `details.component.ts`

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
@ViewChildren(TagDirective) ipt!: QueryList<ElementRef>;
@ViewChild('myform', {static: true}) myform: any;

data: Object;
meta: Object;
datArr: any[] = [];
formCtls: any = {};
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
tabIdx: number = 0;
focusItm: number = 0;
submitNow: boolean = false;

  constructor(private member: MemberService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ipt.changes.subscribe(list=>{
      setTimeout(()=>
        list.filter(itm=>+itm.id===this.focusItm%this.tabIdx).forEach(itm=>{
          if (!this.first_pass) this.navigateTo(itm.id);
        }  
      ),100)
    })
  }

  doSubmit() {
    this.submitNow = true;
  }

  navigateTo(ti: number) {
    console.log(`NAVIGATING TO ITEM WITH TAB INDEX: ${ti}`)
    this.ipt["_results"][ti-1].el.nativeElement.focus();
    this.ipt["_results"][ti-1].el.nativeElement.style.borderWidth = "3px";
  }

  onEnter(e: Event) {

    let cname = (<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>e.target).name;
    let idx = 0;
    for (let itm of this.ipt["_results"]) {
      if (itm.el.nativeElement.name === cname) {
        this.focusItm = (itm.id+1)%this.ipt["_results"].length;
        itm.el.nativeElement.style.borderWidth = "1px";
        break;
      }
    }
    e.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));

  }

  ngOnInit() {
 . . . 
 . . . 

//SET EVERYTHING UP

      this.renderDataArray();
. . . 
. . .

     })

  };

// SET UP ALL THE FormControls, etc. AND THE DATA MODEL datArr USED TO RENDER THE TEMPLATE
  renderDataArray() {
    this.datArr = [];
    this.tabIdx = 0;
    Object.keys(this.meta).forEach((sec,idx) => {
          let rowCnt = this.getActiveArrayLen(sec);
          for (let i = 0; i < rowCnt; i++) {
            Object.keys(this.data[sec]).
              .map((fld,idx)=>{
              let itm = this.data[sec][fld];
                      this.tabIdx += 1;
                      let val =  getVal();
                      let ctlName = sec+this.FLD_SPLIT_CHAR+fld; 
                      this.removeControl(ctlName);
                      this.formCtls[ctlName] = new FormControl(val, {updateOn: 'blur'});
                      this.form.addControl(ctlName, this.formCtls[ctlName]);
                      of(this.tabIdx).
                        pipe(switchMap(ti=>this.formCtls[ctlName].valueChanges.
                          pipe(map(newVal => [newVal,ti]))
                          )
                        ).subscribe(([newVal,ti])=>{
                            if (Array.isArray(itm["value"])) {
                              itm["value"][+(itm["value"].length || 1)-1]=newVal || '';
                            } else {
                              itm["value"]=newVal || '';
                            }
                          this.focusItm = (ti+1)%this.ipt["_results"].length;
                          this.renderDataArray();
                        });
. . . 
. . .
```